# Node.js user authentication using passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript, passport.js

(updated code with serialization functions - still redirects to /failedRedirect)

I'm trying to get simple username/password authentication going using the passport package, but failing. In the example below I've tried to verify that authentication works by basically always returning a valid authentication (regardless of what gets passed), but for some reason it fails and passport redirects to the failed login link.

If anybody could help me out in figuring out how to get this example to simply authenticate anything, I should be able to manage from there.

The code in coffeescript is:

```coffeescript
express = require "express"
passport = require "passport"
LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy

passport.use(new LocalStrategy( (username, password, done) ->
  console.log "LocalStrategy invoked"
  done(null, {id: 1, name: "Marius"})
))

passport.serializeUser (user, done) ->
  done null, user

passport.deserializeUser (obj, done) ->
  done null, obj

app = express.createServer()

app.configure ->
  app.use express.bodyParser()
  app.use express.static("./public")
  app.use express.cookieParser("SOMESECRET")
  app.use express.session
    secret: "SOMESECRET"
    cookie:
      maxAge: 60000
  app.use passport.initialize()
  app.use passport.session()
  app.set "view", "./srv/views"
  app.set "view engine", "jade"

app.get "/login", (req, res) ->
  res.send "login page"

app.post "/login", passport.authenticate("local",
  failureRedirect: "/failedRedirect"
  successRedirect: "/successRedirect"
  failureFlash: true)

app.listen 8082
```

**Solved:** Ok, I believe there were a few reasons why I could not get it working. The serialize stuff may be one (I haven't tested), but since Jared said they were needed, I'm leaving them in (he's the author of Passport). The other confusion may be related to express versions and my confusion with npm. I believe I tested both the latest v2 of express, but I've also tested v3, which I am running now. For version three, you probably should check out the `connect-flash` module on Github as well, as some to the "flash" stuff which is used in Jared's examples was moved out of express v3 (so the module puts it back in...). And finally, make sure you post using the proper named input names (`username` and `password` by default).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks to me like you're missing the necessary user serialization logic to establish a login session.  If I add these two functions to the JavaScript code, it works:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  done(null, obj);
});
```

You'll want to serialize the users according to your needs.  Details are at the bottom of this page: http://passportjs.org/guide/configuration.html

Comment: Updated code in question to include the serialization functions, but authentication still fails at my end. Does the updated code authenticate successfully at your end? Thanks..

Comment: Yeah, it does.  Does your code print out the "LocalStrategy invoked" message.  It might help to mount `app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));` and see if any exceptions are thrown.

Comment: At my end even the "invoked" message does not show. I will try your errorHandler thing at see if anything pops up.

Comment: Nothing pops up. Since you've confirmed things are running at your end, it must be some version mismatch at my end (I'm running everything up to date according to npm). Very annoying that there's not even an error message, it's dead silent. Oh well.. I'll post back if I figure it out. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 10):

The post variable names tend to be the biggest gotcha for people I see having trouble with the local password strategy. It should probably be big and bold in the documentation, and there should probably be config values to change them.

Comment: It looks like there are config values to change them, now.  Bottom of this page: http://passportjs.org/guide/username-password/

Comment: Yep, this one just bit me in the butt for two days.

Answer (score 1):

I have done succsessfully from this link 
http://danialk.github.io/blog/2013/02/23/authentication-using-passportjs/
download sample code from https://github.com/DanialK/PassportJS-Authentication location

Only one change is required in routes.js
change code

```
app.post("/login" ,passport.authenticate('local',{successRedirect : "/",failureRedirect : "/login",  }));
```

To ------------------------------

```
app.post("/login" ,passport.authenticate('local',{failureRedirect : "/login"}), function(req,res){ res.render('your home page here', {user : req.user });});
```