# Node.js Express Passport.js - Data won't serialize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

```
/**
* Module dependencies.
*/

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var login = require('./routes/login');
var register = require('./routes/register');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb');

var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var app = express();




// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3001);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: '1234567890QWERTY'}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(app.router);

var dbc;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb', function(err, db) {
    dbc = db;
});



passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
function(username, password, done) {
    var User = dbc.collection('users');
  User.findOne({ name: /^Harry Torry$/i }, function(err, user) {

       console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
      if(!err) done(null, JSON.stringify(user) );
      else done(err, null)  
  });
}
));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);



// User stuff
app.get('/login', login.get);
app.post('/login',
passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                 failureRedirect: '/login'
                             })
);
app.get('/register', register.get);
app.post('/register', register.post);



http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

So here is my code. For some reason whenever I try to login it says that it can't serialize the data, even though I can console.log(json.stringify()) it?

Any idea as to what the problem is? Here is the stack trace. (I changed all copies of the project name with 'mydb' for security).

```
{"name":"harry torry","registed":"2013-10-23T15:14:27.504Z","_id":"5267e7d3f03965eb2c000001"}
Error: failed to serialize user into session
    at pass (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/index.js:275:19)
    at Passport.serializeUser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/index.js:283:5)
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (/mnt/apshared/mydb/website/node_modules/passport-local/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/http/request.js:43:29)
    at Context.delegate.success (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:194:13)
    at Context.actions.success (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/context/http/actions.js:21:25)
    at verified (/mnt/apshared/mydb/website/node_modules/passport-local/lib/passport-local/strategy.js:83:10)
    at /mnt/apshared/mydb/website/app.js:54:18
    at /mnt/apshared/mydb/website/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection.js:953:5
    at Cursor.nextObject (/mnt/apshared/mydb/website/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:678:5)
    at commandHandler (/mnt/apshared/mydb/website/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:658:14)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the passport.serializeUser function needed to establish a login session. From the [passport docs](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/):

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

try adding those lines of code before the passport.use(new LocalStrategy(...

Also checkout this related question: [Node.js user authentication using passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969299/node-js-user-authentication-using-passport)

Comment: It's resolved now, I didn't realise that I actually had to put each piece of data in instead of the object!